# how to write function for widget?

Tags: python, function, widget, ipython, jupyter

I want to take an input from a user and I want to create widget function to do so. My code is here:

```
from IPython.html import widgets
a = widgets.FloatText(
value=29.900335,
description='latitude:',
disabled=False)
a
```